# How to combine strings in dataframe to list and break up column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm newbie in Python and Pandas. Could you give me advice how to make next manipulation with DataFrame? I have `DataFrame_1`:

```
  id id_name  revenue
0  a  name_a       65
1  a  name_b       65
2  a  name_a       70
3  a  name_b       70
4  a  name_a      121
5  a  name_b      121
```

and I want to make next `DataFrame_2`:

```
  id           id_name  revenue
0  a    name_a, name_b       65
1  a    name_a, name_b       70
2  a    name_a, name_b      121
```

and then make the next `DataFrame_3`

```
  id id_name1 id_name2  revenue
0  a   name_a   name_b       65
1  a   name_a   name_b       70
2  a   name_a   name_b      121
```

So, I want on the first step combine strings with the same `'revenue'`, and on the second step break up column `'id_name'`.

Comment: What's with the `id` variable? If you're only grouping on `Revenue` what do you want to happen in the case that the `Revenue` is the same but `id` is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically achieve the second `DataFrame` with `groupby`

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['id', 'revenue']).id_name.apply(list).reset_index()

  id  revenue           id_name
0  a       65  [name_a, name_b]
1  a       70  [name_a, name_b]
2  a      121  [name_a, name_b]
```

For the third `DataFrame` you can just apply `pandas.Series` to the lists you created above. Here's a solution where you don't need to know how many columns you'll wind up with in the end. It will rename up to 10 properly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df3 = pd.concat([df2[['id', 'revenue']], df2['id_name'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df3.rename(columns=dict((item, 'id_name'+str(item+1)) for item in np.arange(0,10,1)), inplace=True)

  id  revenue id_name1 id_name2
0  a       65   name_a   name_b
1  a       70   name_a   name_b
2  a      121   name_a   name_b
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `groupby` and `cumcount` create the additional key , then we do `unstack`

```
s=df.groupby(['id','id_name']).cumcount()
df['NewId']=s.groupby(s).cumcount()+1
df.set_index(['id','revenue','NewId'])['id_name'].unstack().add_prefix('id_name').reset_index()
Out[137]: 
NewId id  revenue id_name1 id_name2
0      a       65   name_a   name_b
1      a       70   name_a   name_b
2      a      121   name_a   name_b
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution. The first part is identical to @ALollz, but the second uses a list comprehension after calculating the maximum number of id_names per group.

```
# groupby to list of id_names
df2 = df.groupby(['id', 'revenue'])['id_name'].apply(list).reset_index()

# copy df2
df3 = df2.copy()

# calculate max number of id_names
lens = max(map(len, df3['id_name'].values))

# split columns
df3[['id_name'+str(i) for i in range(1, lens+1)]] = df2['id_name'].apply(pd.Series)

# drop unsplit column
df3 = df3.drop('id_name', 1)

print(df3)

  id  revenue id_name1 id_name2 id_name3
0  a       65   name_a   name_b      NaN
1  a       70   name_a   name_b      NaN
2  a      121   name_a   name_b   name_c
```